# SQL LIKE in Excel vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sql-like

I am quite new in working with SQL in VBA and can't seem to get my query working. I searched around in the forums and tried many different solutions but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub RequeteClasseurFerme_Excel2007()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Fichier As String
Dim NomFeuille As String, texte_SQL As String
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CoPo As String

'Définit le classeur fermé servant de base de données
Fichier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B7").Value
'Nom de la feuille dans le classeur fermé
NomFeuille = "Data"
CoPo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B3").Value

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

'--- Connexion ---
With Cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & Fichier & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"""
    .Open
End With
'-----------------

'Request
request_SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & NomFeuille & "$] WHERE [" & NomFeuille & "$].[CodePostal] LIKE '" & CoPo & "%'"

Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Rst = Cn.Execute(request_SQL)

Worksheets("Data2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Rst
'
'... la requête ...
'

'rst.Find
'--- Fermeture connexion ---
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

I am pretty sure it's the like since when I remove it, it does return me all the results.

Comment: You'll have to describe the problem you're having a bit more

Comment: at runtime I am getting an error that would translate to: No values for one or many required parameters" when it gets to Set Rst = Cn.Execute(request_SQL)

Comment: IIR you need to use `*` for a wildcard with that driver.

Comment: I tried replacing the % with * and still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use parameters:

```
Sub RequeteClasseurFerme_Excel2007()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Fichier As String
Dim NomFeuille As String, texte_SQL As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CoPo As String

'Définit le classeur fermé servant de base de données
Fichier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B7").Value

'Nom de la feuille dans le classeur fermé
NomFeuille = "Data"
CoPo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu").Range("B3").Value

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

'--- Connexion ---
With Cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & Fichier & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    .Open
End With
'-----------------

'Request
request_SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & NomFeuille & "$] WHERE [" & NomFeuille & "$].[CodePostal] LIKE ?"


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = Cn
cmd.CommandText = request_SQL
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@postalCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)

cmd.Parameters("@postalCode").Value = CoPo + "%"

Set Rst = cmd.Execute

Worksheets("Data2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Rst
'
'... la requête ...
'

'rst.Find
'--- Fermeture connexion ---
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `HDR=NO;` in your connection string, you tell the driver that the Excel sheet contains no Header row. In that case, you cannot access columns by their name (simply because they have no name). In that case, the RecordSet contains pseudo fieldnames like `F1, F2...`,and you can even use these in a query, eg `where [F1] = 'A'"`. But of course a column like `CodePostal` is not known and accessing it will throw the error you mentioned in the comments.

I assume, however, that your data has a header row, and in that case, simple change the parameter to `HDR=YES;`